# difference between var keyword and without var

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

What is the difference between using var keyword in java script & without using it for a variable?

For example:

```
var x = 14;
```

And `x = 14;`

Are these same or when we declare var x, its a local variable & when it doesn't have var keyword, then its global?

Thanks!

Comment: Mike, see "Linked" section on right for the thing it's a duplicate of.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `var` keyword is used within a function or other non-global scope then that variable's scope **is not global** .

If `var` keyword is not used before a variable name, then that variable's scope **is global** .

Comment: I'd like to add that this wasn't made a syntax error to prevent new comers of the language from abandoning it. Trivial programs will be ok if you accidentally make a global var and manipulate it throughout the function.

Comment: @TomDDD right, that's not a syntax error but possibly a very confusing logical error.  Depends on the actual use. It's the understanding of what happens when leave off `var` that is important and, IMO, what was being asked here

Comment: I totally agree with you. I was just adding the history of why this "feature" exists. There is never a reason to omit. Even when creating global variables. Make a global variable called `global` and assign things to it like a normal assignment

Comment: Is this true even when that x=2 without var is in some specific function? Would that be global too as a whole

Answer (score 3):

Variables declared outside a function become GLOBAL, and all scripts and functions on the web page can access it.

Global variables are destroyed when you close the page.

If you declare a variable, without using "var", the variable always becomes GLOBAL.

Comment: Is there a difference between global and GLOBAL that your using or just to emphasize?